# Whats the directory in the httpd.conf?

Tags: apache

I have a question about apache:

In the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, I see the LoadModule:

```
...
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
...
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
```

I am not sure the `modules/mod_proxy.so` is the `/etc/httpd/conf/` directory, or the httpd's ServerRoot `/etc/httpd/`. Someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those directories are relative to [ServerRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serverroot).  In many installations, that will by default point to `/etc/httpd`, and in `/etc/httpd` you will find a symlink named `modules` pointing to the appropriate directory (on my system that is `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules`).